# PHP - Jquery - simple modal open data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have simply modal:

```
<div id="info" style="display: none;">

    <h3 class="title">User info</h3>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">ID user:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">Login:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

And php script:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
echo '<a href="#" title="" class="open_info">Wyświetl info o '.$user['login'].'</a>';
}
```

JS - Open info click:

```
$('.open_info').click(function(e){
        $('#info').modal({
            autoResize: true
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And i dont know how show info from user this user data.

Help :(

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a hidden div in modal, you should use hidden wrapper div and open inner div in modal.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="info">

    <h3 class="title">User info</h3>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">ID user:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">Login:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
```

Try using this method.

Comment: My modal its ok, if i click a#open_info then dialog is open, but i dont know how in this modal view data user clicked.

here (in modal)
<td>this value</td>

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    echo '<a href="#" title="" class="open_info" id="'.$user['id'].'">Wyświetl info o '.$user['login'].'</a>';
echo '<div id="'.$user['id'].'" style="display: none;" >

    <h3 class="title">User info</h3>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">ID user:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right">Login:</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>';
    }

    $(".open_info").click(function(){
    var getid = $(this).attr("id");
    var docnumbers = new Array();
    $('.open_info').each(function() {
       var selectdoc=this.id;
    if(getid==selectdoc)
    {
    $("#"+selectdoc).show();
    } else {
    $("#"+selectdoc).hide();
    }

    });
    });
```